# undefined variable in laravel5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

i am trying to fetch the values from database and show it on dropdown..while i am trying this i got this error undefined variable usertype..i can't understand where is the mistake..i am new to laravel framework..

Here is my controller:

```
public function get() {
    $usertype = DB::table('user_type')->get();
    return View::make('/home')->with(compact('user_type'));
    return $usertype;

}
```

Here is my view dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cat">User Type</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="user_type_id">
                        @foreach($usertype as $user)
                        <option id="user_type_Id" value="{{$user->id}}" selected="selected">{{ $user->type }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

Can anyone help me..

Comment: there are 2 return in your function.. second one will never execute

Comment: why it will never execute?

Comment: I don't have any idea about laravel but in any programming language.. The first return statement that is executed will terminate the function and its value will be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the variable name in compact function

```
public function get() {
    $usertype = DB::table('user_type')->get();
    return View::make('/home')->with(compact('usertype'));
    return $usertype;

}
```

And also remove the second return statement as it will never execute.

Comment: Undefined variable: usertype (View: /var/www/html/hr_portal/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php)

Comment: is there anything we have to write in model?

Comment: dev please tell me the answer